# How to use CDATA in Spring Boot and Swagger applications

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, swagger, cdata

I've got Java Spring Boot and Swagger project.
I need to use CDATA tags for values between xml tags and for this purpose I've used XMLAdapter:

```
    public class CDATAadapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String>{

    private final static String IN_PROLOG = "<![CDATA[";
    private final static String OUT_PROLOG = "]]";

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {

        return IN_PROLOG.concat(v).concat(OUT_PROLOG);
    }

}

public class Names {

    @XmlAttribute(name="ref")
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The auto-generated version of the product")
    private String key;

    @XmlValue
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=CDATAadapter.class)
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The auto-generated version of the product")
    private String name;

    @XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class NamesContainer {

    @XmlElement(name="listNames")
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The auto-generated version of the product")
    private List<Names> listNames;
```

In the @Get method I'm returning NamesContainer.java as response.

When I execute swagger get method with **media type = "application/json"** everithing is fine:
[image]

but when I use "application/xml" CDATA appends, but **lt** and **gt** are displayed incorrectly in Response Body:
[image]

Is it possible CDATA tags to be displayed as expected (`<![CDATA[ value ]]>`) in swagger Response Body?